# How to get Mocha\Chai working with NativeScript iOS

Tags: unit-testing, chai, nativescript

I cannot seem to get {N} unit testing working on iOS...

1) Requires http with NSAllowsArbitraryLoads.  Id rather not enable this, is there an exception to add that allows it just to be enabled for karma.

2)  Error: Could not find module 'chai'. Computed path '/Users/steve/Library/Developer/CoreSimulato
r/Devices/3607EE15-7B8D-46AE-9DE4-2526D5E91E1F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EBBB37FA-F126-499C-9B
C1-D39179A0F58E/MyApp.app/app/tns_modules/chai'.

This is all the test is

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/mocha/mocha.d.ts" />

import * as helpers from '../scripts/helpers';
import {assert} from 'chai'

describe('Hello World Sample Test:', function () {
    it('Counter should be 42 on start.', function () {
        assert.equal(42, 42); 
    });
});
```

So TypeScript shows no errors, chai is definatly in my node_modules, get all the intellisense goodness.

But indeed like the error says, it doesn't appear to be in that folder with all the other tns stuff (and my other plugins)?

Does anyone have this working or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've experienced seems {N} automatically imports assert as a global function and basically you do not need to import it in your tests. So try to remove:

```
import {assert} from 'chai'
```

and replace it with

```
declare var assert: Chai.AssertStatic;
```

This way TypeScript will not complain and then the tests should also work when executed.

I have working mocha/chai tests here https://github.com/PeterStaev/nativescript-azure-mobile-apps/tree/master/sample so you can take a look for more details.

Comment: I will give er a go thx :)  Needs to be documented as well i think